# How do I get access to "Advanced" properties of civil3d objects via the ViewerSDK or Model Derivative API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ny8B.png)I have tried a variety of methods to get access to advanced properties of civil3d objects either using the viewerSDK or the model derivative api queries, but so far to no avail.

A member of autodesk team originally suggested this method:https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/property-inspector-viewer
but the advanced properties remained hidden.

I have also tried various requests in postman with this url type: {{host}}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{{urn2}}/metadata/{{guid}}/properties:query

The only property categories that I receive are "General" and "Information"

Does anyone have guidance on this ?

Comment: You might need to take advantage of design automation for that.
We have a blog post on that at https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-civil-3d-public-beta